# how to get a list of wordpress used shortcodes with parameters from a pageusing php or jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

I have wordpress page with the following shortcodes
eg

`page1
    [myshortcode id='1']
    [myshortcode id='2']
    [myshortcode id='3']
    ... etc`

Another has 

`page2
    [myshortcode id='4']`

and another has 

`page3
    [myshortcode id='5']`

What I want to do is get a php list of all the shortcodes on any selected page, eg page2, with the paramaters, i.e. the id.

The reason for this is I am writing a plugin wrapper to take an existing shortcode off a page and 'ajax' it, as a link in the currently generated code refreshes the whole page.

So my question is, **how do I get a list of used shortcodes with paramaters from a page, using php or jquery?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check this out: http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Apparently all shortcodes are listed inside the $shortcode_tags:

```
<?php
global $shortcode_tags;
echo "<pre>"; print_r($shortcode_tags); echo "</pre>";
?>
```

You should be able to use this to find the active shortcodes on a PHP page, I guess.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I have tried this, but $shortcode_tags only lists available shortcodes, not the ones you have used with their paramaters, from what i can make out anyway.

Comment: sorry @erik, I did go back and have a look. It does indeed list all used shortcodes, but not the paramaters. I'll looks at it some more and take it from there.

Comment: Yes I understand, but I was more thinking about using the list to create regex statements which can recognize the shortcodes in the PHP file. Something like ```\[shortcodeNameFromList(.*?)\]```. But you still have to find them before they're replaced with actually html

Comment: Yes, I was busy delving into using regex when I asked the question, cos it's giving me a headache :)

Comment: Ok, it got me close enough to mark as correct. The final working code is as follows `echo "<pre>"; 
 global $pagename;
 global $wpdb;
 $sqlstr='SELECT post_content FROM wp_posts WHERE post_content LIKE "%[schsspiffy%" AND post_name="'.$pagename.'"';
 $results = $wpdb->get_results($sqlstr);
 preg_match_all("^\[schsspiffy(.*?)\]^",$results[0]->post_content,$out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
 print_r($out);
 echo "</pre>";`

Comment: Thanks! No problem ;) Your code looks good! Glad you got it working.